# sending value to another form

Tags: c#, textbox, listbox

When sending a value from a **textbox in form2** to a **listbox in form1**,
I am getting a `NullReferenceException` error.

The handler code is:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ListBox LB = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["Project_list"] as ListBox;
    LB.Items.Add(Project_name.Text);           
}
```

What is going wrong in it?

Comment: maybe Form1 is not opened and Application.OpenForms["Form1"] returns null

Comment: Check `Application.OpenForms["Form1"]` as well as `.Controls["Project_list"]` if any of those is null. (Add breakpoint and inspect should do the trick)

Comment: well.. it should be. From1 is the win form that starts up. then i click a button to open up form2

Comment: Is Project_list on the form itself or it is inside another container on the form? `Controls` is checking only first level controls.

Comment: override the the constructor of the next form and pass it as an argument in the constructor.. that might help

Comment: I would prefer to pass the controls/values you need as parameter to the constructor of form2 and save them into fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for **demo purposes...** Check this code, set a breakpoint and see what happens.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // i do assume there is a class Form1 within your project?!
    Form1 frm = (Form1) Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
    // look for Project_list within your Form1.Controls, true to search all childControls too
    Control[] ctrls = frm.Controls.Find("Project_list", true);
    if (ctrls.Length >0)
    {
        ListBox LB =  ctrls[0] as ListBox;
        if (LB!=null)
            LB.Items.Add(Project_name.Text);           
        else
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Doooooh");
    }
}
```

This is just an example to see what's wrong with your code!

Comment: I got it to work. i was forgetting I was working with a tabControl and tabpage1.

thanks for your effort. my bad :>